# Unable to match the string "help" in the string "[help]" using regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm not able to get this to match correctly.  It only prints "[help]" but I want it to match the characters inside the brackets.

want:

```
[help]
help
```

code:

```
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[(\\w+)\\]");
        Matcher m = p.matcher("[help]");
        m.find();


        for (int i=0;i<m.groupCount(); i++) {
            System.out.println(m.group(i));
        }
```

Comment: You probably need more backslashes.

Comment: Well it's usually the case with Java REs :) (Got beaten to the answer before I even finished submitting to ideone)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check for `<=` for the groupCount. Like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= m.groupCount(); i++) {
```

From the [Matcher Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#groupCount%28%29):

> Any non-negative integer smaller than or equal to the value returned by this method is guaranteed to be a valid group index for this matcher.